# Nutch sitemap command won't work

Tags: web-crawler, sitemap, nutch

I tried to use this command $ bin/nutch sitemap

but it gives me the following error

Error: Could not find or load main class sitemap

It's mentioned on the website http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/SitemapFeature
but it does not work for me. I am using Nutch 1.7

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am using version 1.9 and still have the same issue. Anyone was able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess by looking at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1465
it seems that its not supported in the current version

It might be released in 1.8 version.. I am currently using 1.7